# Ignoring generic argument halfway through scala type hierarchy

Tags: scala, generics, existential-type

I have a parallel hierarchy of types that generically reference each other: One through plain generics, the other via a type variable.

However, one of the parallel hierarchies is shorter than the other, and this is causing me issues.

I have provided a code snippet below, and the compiler errors are added as inline comments above the lines that cause the issues:

- `type arguments [Foo[_],FooKey] do not conform to trait PrimaryKey's type parameter bounds [A <: Entity[A],B <: PrimaryKey[A,B]]`
- `overriding type K in trait Entity with bounds <: PrimaryKey[A,Foo.this.K]; type K has incompatible type`

The issue is that I want `FooKey` to not be generic, as for `FooKey` it doesn't matter how exactly the implementation of `Foo` is parameterized.

```scala
package com.scalatest

object Database {
  trait PrimaryKey[A <: Entity[A], B <: PrimaryKey[A, B]] {
    this: B =>
  }

  trait Entity[A <: Entity[A]] {
    this: A =>

    type K <: PrimaryKey[A, K]
    val id: K
  }

  //Error:(17, 24) type arguments [com.scalatest.Database.Foo[_],com.scalatest.Database.FooKey] do not conform to trait PrimaryKey's type parameter bounds [A <: com.scalatest.Database.Entity[A],B <: com.scalatest.Database.PrimaryKey[A,B]]
  //  class FooKey extends PrimaryKey[Foo[_], FooKey]
  class FooKey extends PrimaryKey[Foo[_], FooKey]

  trait Foo[A <: Foo[A]] extends Entity[A] {
    this: A =>
    //Error:(24, 19) overriding type K in trait Entity with bounds <: com.scalatest.Database.PrimaryKey[A,Foo.this.K];
    // type K has incompatible type
    //    override type K = FooKey
    override type K = FooKey
  }

  class FooImpl(val id: FooKey) extends Foo[FooImpl]
}
```

I managed to use an existential type instead of `Foo[_]` in my declaration of `FooKey`, in conjunction with making all `A`s covariant, but then I am still left with the 2nd error.

```scala
  class FooKey extends PrimaryKey[Foo[A] forSome { type A <: Foo[A] }, FooKey]
```

Comment: Do you really need F-bounded stuff like `A <: Entity[A]`? Remove inheritance and everything will become MUCH more simple.

Comment: plz, give us an example of how you are going to use FooImpl and FooKey in the code?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, as in reality my `FooImpl` is a lot more complex than what I described in this minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that

> for `FooKey` it doesn't matter how exactly the implementation of `Foo` is parameterized.

You want to override with `FooKey` the type `K <: PrimaryKey[A, K]` where `A` is the same as in `trait Entity[A <: Entity[A]] {...`
And you make this overriding in `trait Foo[A <: Foo[A]] {...` so `FooKey` must satisfy condition `K <: PrimaryKey[A, K]` (this is not just upper bound since `K` is present in both sides) for every `A <: Foo[A]` so `FooKey` should be quantified universally rather than existentially.

So you should add type parameter to `FooKey`

```
  object Database {
    trait PrimaryKey[A <: Entity[A], B <: PrimaryKey[A, B]] {
      this: B =>
    }

    trait Entity[A <: Entity[A]] {
      this: A =>

      type K <: PrimaryKey[A, K]
      val id: K
    }

    class FooKey[A <: Foo[A]] extends PrimaryKey[A, FooKey[A]]

    trait Foo[A <: Foo[A]] extends Entity[A] {
      this: A =>
      override type K = FooKey[A]
    }

    class FooImpl(val id: FooKey[FooImpl]) extends Foo[FooImpl]
  }
```